# Get the code of the project depending on the select name in the dropdown

Tags: mysql

The data in my table looks like this

```
Name    |   Code        |   Quantity    |
Prod1   |   PR.01.14    |   100         |
Prod1   |   PR.01.13    |   1000        |
Prod2   |   PR.02.14    |   200         |
Prod2   |   PR.02.13    |   2000        |
```

What I would like to happen is when the user selects Prod1 on the dropdown that I have it will show the code for that Name.

```
Name    |   Code        |   Quantity    |
Prod1   |   PR.01.14    |   100         |
Prod1   |   PR.01.13    |   1000        |
```

Its all on the same table. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fetch all column from your table and filter (using `WHERE clause`) by the name selected from dropdown

```
select Name,
Code,
Quantity 
from my_code_table
where Name = 'Prod1'
```